# Rails Nokogiri Retrieve both Channel Title and Item Title

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rss, nokogiri

So I have the following Nokogiri rake task:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

namespace :rss do
  desc "Fetch rss feed"
  task :fetch => :environment do
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.themusicvoid.com/feed"))
    @info = doc.xpath('//item').take(5).map do |i|
        News.create(:title => i.xpath('title').inner_text)
    end
  end
end
```

This gets me the title for each individual 'Item'... but I would also like each database entry to contain the channel name in a string called "site".

So something like:

```
News.create(:title => i.xpath('title').inner_text, :site => i.xpath('channeltitle').inner_text)
```

I'm just entirely unsure of how to make that happen. Since both the Channel and the Item name are 'title' I'm not exactly sure how to get Nokogiri to differentiate between the two. I know that I would have to include '//channel' somewhere in the xpath, but I'm not entirely certain how I could get nokogiri to make call one "itemtitle" and the other "channeltitle".  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the channel title is the same for all items, you should be able to get the channel title from the `doc` and then use it during the iteration of each `item`.

You could get the title using:

```
channel_title = doc.at_xpath('rss/channel/title').inner_text
```

And then use it within the iteration of each item:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

namespace :rss do
  desc "Fetch rss feed"
  task :fetch => :environment do
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.themusicvoid.com/feed"))
    channel_title = doc.at_xpath('rss/channel/title').inner_text
    @info = doc.xpath('//item').take(5).map do |i|
        News.create(:title => i.xpath('title').inner_text, :site => channel_title)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. But ultimately I will have multiple feeds. So how can I format this so that I get the "site" for each feed?

Comment: Do you mean that there would be multiple channels within the same feed (ie `http://www.themusicvoid.com/feed` would have multiple channel nodes) or that you would iterate through multiple pages (eg doing the above for `http://www.themusicvoid.com/feed` and `http://www.anothersite.com/feed`)?

Comment: Multiple pages: musicvoid.com/feed and anothersite.com/feed.

Comment: Sorry, I do not any rails/rss experience. However, I would think that as you are iterating through each of the pages, you would set the `channel_title` each time you get a new page or `doc`.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Great job with no rails experience.